# Is there a way to reload a flask app without code or file changes?

Tags: python, flask

As flask app will reload itself after it detect changes with the `debug=True` option, I would like to know if there is a way to manually trigger the reload without making any changes to the code and files.

Preferably trigger the reload when a user accesses "url"/reloadFlask

```py
@app.route('/reloadFlask', methods = ['POST'])
def reloadFlask():
    # Some magic here
```

Comment: The feature exists to reload the code in development if it was changed. Without a code change it makes less sense. If you are trying to use any side-effect of the reload, like a resource that is reloaded, you might have made a bad design choice at some point.

Comment: Maybe you could `touch` the file containing your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your application as a service (for example via `systemctl`), just call one of the many functions available in python to execute a command.

For example:

```
import os

@app.route('/reloadFlask', methods = ['POST'])
def reloadFlask():
    os.system("systemctl restart <your_service_name>")
```

or:

```
import subprocess

@app.route('/reloadFlask', methods = ['POST'])
def reloadFlask():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["systemctl", "restart", "<your_service_name>"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: This imply that your service is running as root as well.

Comment: removed the `sudo`

Comment: @MarkSetchell's method at the question's comment section of using `Path.touch()` is also OK if it doesn't matter changing the last modification time of the files.